# React/Redux - Issue iterating json from mapStateToProps

Tags: json, ajax, redux

I have a React Native app on which I'm trying to apply Redux. It's the first time I try to use Redux, so I think I'm not seeing the elephant in the room.

The problem is that I can't access my props data (generated with mapStateToProps). Here's my code:

reducer.js (in the console log I see the json objects just fine)

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  etiquetas: []
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ETIQUETAS_SUCCESS:
      //console.log("payload: "+action.payload);
      return { ...state, etiquetas: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

component.js (in the console.log I see my data, BUT it seems that it's all in one object now, this is probably what I'm not seeing).

```
class EtiquetasList extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.FetchEtiquetas();
  }

  renderEtiquetas() {
    //console.log("etq: "+JSON.stringify(this.props.etiquetas));
    if ( this.props.etiquetas.length == 0 ) {
      return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00ff00" />
    } else {    
      return this.props.map(etiqueta =>
        <EtiquetaDetail key={etiqueta.id} etiqueta={etiqueta} />
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        {this.renderEtiquetas()}
      </ScrollView>
    );

  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    etiquetas: state.etiquetas
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { FetchEtiquetas })(EtiquetasList);
```

The map function is for Arrays, not Objects, I know. That's part of my old code.

action.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { FETCH_ETIQUETAS, FETCH_ETIQUETAS_SUCCESS, FETCH_ETIQUETAS_FAILURE } from './types';

const url= 'https://e.dgyd.com.ar/wp-json/wp/v2/etiquetas?_embed&per_page=7';

const fetchSuccess = (dispatch, data)=> {
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_ETIQUETAS_SUCCESS,
    payload: data
  });
}

export function FetchEtiquetas() {

  return function (dispatch) {
      axios.get( url )
        .then(response => {
          dispatch({ type: FETCH_ETIQUETAS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data })
        } );
  }
}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import DataReducer from './DataReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  etiquetas: DataReducer
});
```

So, my questions are:

1. Why is is this always returning undefined?
   this.props.etiquetas.length == 0
2. Why mapStateToProps seems to convert my array of objects into a single object? is this why I have to use JSON.stringify in the console log?
3. and finally, how do I access my data in the component?

Thank you much in advance!

Comment: are you sure that  action.payload is array not json?

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't post the actual important part of the code your trying to debug.   Can we see your action/action creator that actually executes what looks like an AJAX request for some data.

Comment: Also, can you show us what your root reducer file looks like

Comment: @DanielZuzevich just added the action file and the reducer root, sorry

Comment: in your mapStateToProps function, update it to this, etiquetas: state.etiquetas.etiquetas and re-fresh and let me know if anything changes.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich yes sir!!! that did the trick! also had to update the map line to: return this.props.etiquetas.map(etiqueta =>
        <EtiquetaDetail key={etiqueta.id} etiqueta={etiqueta} />
      );
Thank you so much!

Comment: No prob. Would you mind accepting my answer below?

Comment: @DanielZuzevich sure! thank you again! I was stuck with that little thing since last night.

Comment: Haha. I've been there many a times. Redux is hard to understand. Hopefully this problem helped you understand it a little bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, is just the way that you structured your reducer.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  etiquetas: []
};
```

The code above means that you are creating an object, with a property named "etiquetas" that holds an empty array initially.

In your root reducer file, you import that object, and assign it the name, "etiquetas". So really what your reducer is returning is this:

```
etiquetas: {
  etiquetas: [your array of data]
}
```

This would explain why you complained about receiving an object. There are two ways to rectify this,

**One:** Change the mapStateToProps function to this,

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    etiquetas: state.etiquetas.etiquetas
  };
};
```

**Two:** Change your reducer to look like this,

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ETIQUETAS_SUCCESS:
      //console.log("payload: "+action.payload);
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This will make sure your reducer returns just an array, not an object with an array inside of it stored in a property. Its up to you to decide which you like better.

Comment: Thank you very much! I went with number 1 and worked just fine :)